# Map Range Node in Blender 2.79

Tags: node-editor

Where the Map range node is located in Blender 2.79?

I have tried to find it but could not do it.

Answer (score 2):

The *Map Range* node was introduced to Blender in version 2.81, it didn't exist before that so you won't find it in 2.79, sorry.

Comment: You can recreate it using other maths nodes though, for instance a simple linear interpolation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: @Gorgious That's right, I thought about showing a workaround but a) I got some trouble here and don't have time and b) I would always prefer working with a newer version of Blender anyway.

Comment: Hehe yeah no worries you answered the question. I just wanted to add the information if the OP still wants to find a solution for themselves :) cheers